# Salesforce Marketing Cloud Reply Mail Management Not Working for Internal Users (Azure)

Tags: marketing-cloud, reply-mail-management

We've discovered that our Reply Mail Management is failing for internal email addresses.
It works perfectly fine for external users but not internal users.
We're using Exchange/Office 365 on Azure for our emails.
Because we're sending a lot of messages to our employees from marketing cloud, we need to ensure replies can be received.
Salesforce support is unable to replicate it because it's working fine for external users.
Anyone run into this and/or (hopefully) found a solution?

Comment: Sounds like an internal email server firewall issue and nothing can be done from the SFMC side.

Comment: Has your sending IP address and domain been whitelisted for your company's mail server?

Comment: I've been told it's whitelisted. It was working previously but suddenly stopped.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this [issue](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000338236&type=1):

> There's an issue with Microsoft Outlook that causes it to ignore the 'Reply to' address in the message header. Instead, Outlook sends the reply to the default 'From' address and bypasses RMM.

When you hit reply in outlook what is the to address? is it reply-XXXX@XXXX.com or is it the from address?

Comment: When you reply its reply-xwsdfa34s....@oursalesforcedomain